# Assistance with Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I’m new to LINQ and need some help with a query.

I need all of the **Resources** from (tblResources) that belong to the ***Anonymous***, and ***Public*** **ResourceGroups** (tblResourceGroups).  In addition, I also need all of the **Resources** that belong to any of the **ResourceGroups** that the ***currentUser*** belongs to.

If the ***currentUser*** isn’t logged in (currentUser == null) then only **Resources** belonging to ***Anonymous***, and ***Public*** **ResourceGroups** should be returned.

NOTE: My data model does not contain an entity for tblResourceAccess.  I'm not sure why this entity wasn't added when the model was created.

```
        string currentUser = IdentityHelper.GetUserIdFromRequest(Context.Request);

        var result = from r in DbContext.Resources                                                                           
                     where r.Active == true // && r.ResourceGroups?????                         
                     select new
                     {                                                          
                         ResourceTypeName = r.ResourceType.Name,
                         Name = r.Name,
                         Version = r.Version,
                         Description = r.Description,
                         Path = r.Path,
                         Active = r.Active
                     };
```

[image: Entity Data Models]

[image: Database Tables]

Comment: Your first step should be recreating your Models then so that the Access table does get the data object.

Answer (score 1):

The `tblResourceAccess` was abstracted away by EF and the `ResourceGroups` property added to the `Resource` table to provide the functionality.  Using this relationship we can piece together the following query:

```
from r in DBContext.Resources.ToList()
where (currentUser == null 
        && ("anonymous,public").Contains(
            r.ResourceGroups.Name.ToLower()))
    || (currentUser != null)
select new
    {                                                          
        ResourceTypeName = r.ResourceType.Name,
        Name = r.Name,
        Version = r.Version,
        Description = r.Description,
        Path = r.Path,
        Active = r.Active
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Any idea why "The name 'r' does not exist in the current context? Include(r.ResourceGroups)

Comment: You can safely remove the Include, I put it there for completeness.

Comment: After removing the Include, I get this error.   Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Web.Models.ResourceGroup>' does not contain a definition for 'ResourceGroup' and no extension method 'ResourceGroup' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Web.Models.ResourceGroup>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Eagle\Web\Web\Support\Downloads.aspx.cs 51 50 Web

Comment: 'ResourceGroup' or 'ResourceGroups'? Are you missing the 's'?

Comment: r.ResourceGroups.Name.ToLower - Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Web.Models.ResourceGroup>' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Web.Models.ResourceGroup>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Eagle\Web\Web\Support\Downloads.aspx.cs 51 55 Web

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a **lot** of trial and **error**!  I'm not sure if this is best way performance wise to implement this query, but it works.

Thanks for your help **@The Sharp Ninja**!

```
string currentUser = IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);

var resources = from r in DbContext.Resources                            
                where r.ResourceGroups.Any(
                      rg => rg.Name == "Anonymous" || 
                      rg.Name == "Public" || 
                      rg.ResourceUserGroups.Any(ug => ug.UserID == currentUser))
                select r;
```